# Testing a (big) collection retrieved from a db

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, collections, list, integration-testing

I'm currently doing integration testing on a database and I have the following sql statement:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2010 20:30:00");
var result = datacontext.Repository<IObject>().Where(r => r.DateTime > date).First();
Assert.IsFalse(result.Finished);
```

I need to test if the results retrieved from the statement, where the given date is less then the date of the object, have Finished set to False. I do not know how many results I get back and currently I'm getting the first object of the list and check if that object has Finished set to false. I know testing only the first item of the list is not valid testing, as a solution for that I could iterate through the list and check all items on Finished, but putting logic in a Test is kinda going against the concept of writing 'good' tests.

So my question is:
Does anyone have a good solution of how to properly test the results of this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go the other way around, check if you have any result in that date range that **is** finished.

If there is any, then your test should fail.

I can't test any fancier code, so I'll give you a simple way:

```
int noOfResultsFinished = datacontext.Repository<IObject>()
      .Where(r => r.DateTime > date && r.Finished).Count();

if (noOfResultsFinished > 0)
{
     // fail test
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment! Why didn't I think of that :P

Comment: Because nobody has The Inspiration on his side all the time :)